# How to get a random file out of a folder?

Tags: java, file, random

selectedFiles.addAll(getMiscFiles("before"));

This code choose all the files from the folder, but I need to choose one random file only. I couldn't figure out how to do, so every advice is very welcome.

Comment: You might want to add more information about the programming language/platform you are using

Answer (score 1):

If getMiscFiles() returns a list you can:
  selectedFiles.addAll(getMiscFiles("before").get(0));
This will get the first file from the list and add it to selectedFiles

Comment: That is great. Can I get a random file somehow from the same "before" folder?

Comment: I don't know why you insist on the "randomness" of the file, but something like the following would likely work:

List<File> miscFiles = getMiscFiles("before");
Random randomizer = new Random();
int randomFileIndex = randomizer.nextInt(miscFiles.size()-1);
selectedFiles.addAll(miscFiles.get(randomFileIndex)); 

You have to adjust the List Generic type as per your preferences.